# Solving the following parametric equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

> Solve the following parametric equation:
>
> $$\frac{-(3\cos t-x)}{2\sin t-y}=-\frac{2\cos t}{3\sin t}$$

So I need to find the parametric equation of the thing in terms of $t$.
But I am confused as to how to do it since I have two variables but only one equation.

If anyone could help, it would mean a lot!
Thank you :)

Comment: The wording of your problem is incomplete. If you don't have two equations (or more specifications in addition), an expression on parametric form doesn't exists.

Comment: for $t=\pi\pm2\pi n$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$, this simplifies down to $x=0$.  This would be a single solid line at $x=0$, since it holds true for all $y$.  for $t=\lim_{k\to n}\pm2\pi k$, the limit for both sides ends up stating $y\to0$ as $t\to\pm2\pi k$.  Take a moment to see what kind of graph this would be, if it were a parametric equation.  Imagine tracing it from $t=-2\pi$ to $t=2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting into:

$$y-2\sin t=\frac{3\sin t}{2\cos t} (x-3\cos t) \quad \cdots \cdots \: (*)$$

which is an equation of normal of the ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1$$

The envelope of $(*)$ is the centre of curvature of the ellipse (or ellipse evolute):

\begin{align*}
  (x,y) &=
  \left(
    \frac{3^2-2^2}{3} \cos^{3} t,
    \frac{2^2-3^2}{2} \sin^{3} t
  \right) \\
  &=
  \left(
     \frac{5}{3} \cos^{3} t,
    -\frac{5}{2} \sin^{3} t
  \right)
\end{align*}

> Equation of normal for $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ at $(a\cos t,b\sin t)$ is
>
> $$ax\sec t-by\csc t=a^2-b^2$$